# How to remove the `require is not defined` console error when exporting in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, require

I have a .ts file where I'm exporting a `const` variable along with with an `inventory`:

3_enumerable.ts:

```
export interface InventoryItem {
    displayName: string;
    trackingNumber: string | number;
    furnitureType: InventoryItemType;
    cost: number;
    createDate?: Date;
}

export const inventoryItems: InventoryItem[] = [
    {displayName: 'item1', trackingNumber: '1234', furnitureType: InventoryItemType.Computer, cost: 10, createDate: new Date('2020-01-01')},
    {displayName: 'item2', trackingNumber: '5678', furnitureType: InventoryItemType.Computer, cost: 30},
    {displayName: 'item3', trackingNumber: 9101, furnitureType: InventoryItemType.Computer, cost: 30}
]
```

I'm then importing them in another .ts file (4_functions.ts):

```
import {InventoryItem, inventoryItems} from './3_enumerable'
```

However, I notice that with that when I import the `const` into `4_functions.ts` it compiles to using the `require` function in `4_functions.js`

4_functions.js:

```
var _3_enumerable_1 = require("./3_enumerable");
```

FYI- If I don't import the `const` and only import the `interface` the `require` doesn't compile in `4_functions.js`

However, now I'm also getting a console.log error due to this `require` function in `4_functions.js`:

```
4_functions.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at 4_functions.js:3:23
```

How do I remove this error?

Also this is my `tsconfig.js` file-- do I need to edit something here?:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5", 
    "outDir": "build",
  },

  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: `require` and `import/export` are not interoperable.

Comment: If you don't want to use `require`, what do you want to use? Are you trying to create JavaScript modules? Are you trying to bundle your modules into a single file? What is your target platform?